# Show that 5 is not in the following sequence of primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let us define the sequence of primes in the following way: $p_1 = 2$, and if $p_1,p_2...p_k$ are given, then let $p_{k+1}$ be the largest prime divisor of $p_1p_2...p_k + 1$ (so $p_2=3, p_3=7, etc.)$. Show that 5 is not in this sequence.

This is one of the challenging questions from my book, which is fitting because I honestly have no idea about how to do this. If anyone could solve this and explain it, it would be a huge help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The sequence is [OEIS A000946](http://oeis.org/A000946) which starts $2, 3, 7, 43, 139, 50207, 340999, 2365347734339, 4680225641471129$  I would be surprised if it ever decreases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have $p_1=2,p_2=3,p_3=7$ the only way $5$ can appear is if $p_1p_2p_3\ldots p_k+1$ is a power of $5$.  Otherwise there will be some higher prime factor.  $5^m \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ but the product of primes is equivalent to $2 \pmod 4$ so the product of primes plus one is not a power of $5$.

Comment: Very nice proof!